# 0x88 chess board representation

Tags: python, wxpython, artificial-intelligence, chess

I am trying to make a 2 player chess program with a GUI in wxPython that is able to validate moves and follow every chess rule.

Right now, I am at the beginning of my design and figuring out which board representation technique I should use. I recently thought the obvious, two dimensional array, but then I read about the [0x88 board representation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Board_representation_%28chess%29#0x88_method) that is supposedly faster in terms of lookups and logically checks if the square is inside the chessboard or not. But, if I make a program without AI, there is no need to check if someone has moved a move that is outside of the board.

Is there any other advantages with the 0x88 representation that I'm not aware of and which one would you recommend , the 8x8 approach or 0x88. Also, would it be easy to first use a 8x8 representation , and then later, maybe if I decide to add AI, use the 0x88 one ?
Thank you very much for your thoughts.

Comment: You're not really going to see much of a performance difference with consumer computers today. My *phone* has enough processing power to play chess — and beat me consistently.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I agree with you that if you're not doing AI, there's not a lot of reason to micro-optimize like that.

One suggestion that I would make is that if you're considering switching from 8x8 to 0x88 (and in general, for good code quality) is that you should abstract out as much of the board access  logic as possible into functions. For example, write and use a

```
getPieceAtLocation(char file, int rank)
```

and call

```
Piece p = getPieceAtLocation('e', 2);
```

or something along those lines. That way, if you decide to change your mind, you just need to re-write the logic in `getPieceAtLocation` rather than changing every place where you have to use it.

Answer (score 4):

The "standard" board representations that have been mentioned (0x88, bitboards, etc) all have a goal of extreme optimization. Specifically, extreme optimization in two areas:

1. Make it go fast, the faster the better
2. Providing the programmer with a better toolbox to guide the chess tree search, which improves the AI

The "standard" board representations are only "standard" within the group of people who write chess programs and have them play competitively online against other people and other computers. This is clearly not what you are after, so I would not advise you to use any of those methods.

Those "standard" approaches are literally trying to use bit-twiddling tricks to save 1-2 CPU cycles here and there. The fact that you are using Python makes saving a few cycles here and there completely pointless. Python is great, but it's not fast, at all.

Python gives you a lot of good tools. Use them. Your program will be slow, and there's nothing wrong with that. It won't "feel" slow, and that's all that matters. I would absolutely use Python if I were you, and I would not give a second thought to using any of these bit-twiddling ideas in Python. If you are writing in C or assembler, bit twiddling is fun. In Python it's pointless.

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe your decision to use AI should have any bearing on whether your board representation can include checks if the square is inside the chessboard.  That is, whether or not it is a computer or a player making a move, it is advantageous for your underlying representation to be able to detect and gracefully handle moves involving invalid squares.

Personally, I believe in the bit-board approach--I found that this approach was both very speedy (since it relies on bitwise operations) and fits logically with modern 64-bit architectures.  On top of that, whether you decide to do AI or not will not require any redesign of your representation, so it is more future-proof too.

Compare to 0x88, it is more memory-friendly, having every piece represented by a single bit and it gets more friendly the fewer pieces on the board.  While memory may not be the largest concern on modern computers, its a perk that has no real downside either.

With bitboards, one bitwise operation calculates many pieces' move validity and only a few more for the remaining tokens mean that you can determine hundreds of possible moves (compounded by how much move-depth you desire) in the fastest possible fashion, which I anecdotally believe runs laps around 0x88.

If you are interested in some bitboard related code, see my project [THUD!](http://thud.svn.sourceforge.net/) (a board game not very like chess in playrules, but entirely similar in how you would enforce them, represent the board and the pieces.  Likewise, there's an AI designed too (multithreaded even), which illustrates the extensibility of bitboards.  And if you have any questions, I'd be happy to personally field them.

Answer (score 0):

You should also check out some of the other wxPython (or other) chess projects for ideas:

- http://sourceforge.net/projects/yapcp/  (wx)
- http://yakinikuman.wordpress.com/2009/04/14/python-chess-v-04/  (tkinter)
- PyGame - http://www.pygame.org/tags/chess